# Results of arpalert to json in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, arp

I'm trying to create a program who'll catch the mac address connections. For this, I take the /var/log/arpalert.log and create a dict. with the results in JSON. I'm a beginner in Python.

For now, I have the arpalert log to a file.txt. I take this file and create a dictionary in an other file. I transform the result to JSON format.
But the problem is the "format" of my dictionary. In the Json format I have all the informations of one connection in a key, and all the informations of another connection in the value of the key.

But what I want is a key "mac" with the address in value, a key "ip" with the address in value, etc...

This is my code for now :

```
from json import dumps, dump

from itertools import izip

def get_log(source, destination):

     log = open(source, 'r')
     fil_dest = open(destination, 'w')
     txt = log.readline()
     while txt:
          fil_dest.write(txt)
          txt = log.readline()
     log.close()
     fil_dest.close()

def to_json(source, destination):

     fil_dest = open(destination, 'w')

     with open(source, 'r') as lines:
          txt = lines.readlines()
          wanted_lines = txt[0:]
          i = iter(wanted_lines)
          dict_log = dict(izip(i, i))

          dump(dict_log, fil_dest, sort_keys=True, indent=1)
     lines.close()
     fil_dest.close()

get_log('/var/log/arpalert.log', 'arpalert_strings.txt')
to_json('arpalert_strings.txt', 'json_conversion.txt')
```

and the result in JSON ("key": "value")

```
"Oct  8 14:45:52 arpalert: seq=2, mac=a2:e5:68:3c:16:f1, ip=192.168.1.19, type=new, dev=p3p1, vendor=\"(null)\"\n": "Oct  8 14:45:52 arpalert: seq=3, mac=04:e8:ca:a8:6f:b8, ip=192.168.1.19, type=new, dev=p3p1, vendor=\"(null)\"\n",
"Oct  9 09:41:46 arpalert: Auto selected device: bluetooth0\n": "Oct  9 09:41:46 arpalert: [./capture.c 181] ioctl[19] : No such device\n",
```

Anybody can help me please ? I tried with regex but I'm lost and I losing my mind !

Comment: Could you post a sample of how the `arpalert.log` file looks like?

Comment: yes of course it looks like                                                                  cat arpalert_strings.txt 
Oct  8 14:45:11 arpalert: Selected device: p3p1
Oct  8 14:45:35 arpalert: seq=1, mac=86:b6:8c:1f:b5:98, ip=192.168.1.19, type=new, dev=p3p1, vendor="(null)"
Oct  8 14:45:52 arpalert: seq=2, mac=a2:e5:68:3c:16:f1, ip=192.168.1.19, type=new, dev=p3p1, vendor="(null)"